# Upgrading personal AKS cluster

Tags: azure, kubernetes, aks

I have a personal Kubernetes cluster on AKS and Azure is making it mandatory for me to update the Kubernetes version in order to add a new node into the cluster.

Now that I have to do this, I would like to know about the risks. I know that it is a personal cluster, but I would like some tips and to learn how to do it the right way beforehand anyways:

1. I have a single node pool with a single node;
2. I have some ingresses and **I would like to know if the IP addresses of the Ingresses would be affected in case I update the Kubernetes version and/or add new nodes**;
3. I have some persistent volumes and **I would like to know if these volumes would be affected in case I update the Kubernetes version and/or add new nodes**;
4. I checked the API deprecation warnings with `kubectl get --raw /metrics | grep apiserver_requested_deprecated_apis` and there are a few deprecations to fix;
5. I checked the API deprecation warnings with `kubent` and there are a few deprecations to fix;
6. I checked the API deprecation warnings with at the AKS upgrade page on the Portal and there are a few deprecations to fix.

About the last 3 items above, I would like to ask: Considering that I fixed the deprecated APIs stuff, **is the default AKS upgrade process safe by default or could it break the cluster and/or cause downtime?**

Comment: This should be off-topic due to personal use, but it definitely applies to professional ones too.